# Multiple Html Files sent at the same server for multiple people

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, npm

i'm making a sort of a game on a website, and the game has players ( of course) and when they open a new room, each one gets assigned to a role basically
each role has a " power "
what i want to know is, how can i make each role for each player, because some players wait for other players input
And there's some html files that won't get shown to other players, hence "power",
so how can i get multiple html files to get shown for some people but not others ?

Comment: Hi Haidar ezio, welcome to the community. This question is too vague, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to focus on where you're having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like a job for websockets.

https://javascript.info/websocket